# How to access the parent element of the element that was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

how to place my delete button so that `onclick` will return the whole `<tr>`

in the below code my `jquery` is clueless as which row to delete because onclick

is returning only `this` (i,e `<td><button>Delete</button></td>`)

**please provide some optimal solution**

```js
$('#example').on("click", "button", function(){

  console.log($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>17</td>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>26</td>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>31</td>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>34</td>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>44</td>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>57</td>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it returns the `<button>` (and not the `<td><button>Delete</button></td>`).

If you want to find the `<tr>` parent you should use the `parents` function:

```
$(this).parents('tr');
```

Here is the fix to your code:

```js
$('#example').on("click", "button", function(){
  console.log($(this).parents('tr'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>17</td>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>26</td>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>31</td>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>34</td>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>44</td>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>57</td>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td><button>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#example').on("click", "button", function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').remove(); //note the 's' in parents()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation working just as well

```js
$('#example').on("click", "button", function(e){
  $(e.target).closest('tr').remove();
});
```